# Относительный путь к файлу

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня такая проблема: в Спринге поднимаю бин, в бине есть проперти - имя файла, из которого нужно считывать инфо. Так вот, там прописываю имя файла без пути: `"myfile.txt"`. После этого при инициализации данного поля бина пытаюсь получить путь к файлу через `*.class.getResourceAsStream`, но получаю на выходе `null`. Что самое интересное, что если я переименовываю файл в `myfile.properties`, то все нормально находится и отрабатывает. Объясните пожалуйста, в чем проблема.

Comment: А сам файл где лежит? Рядом с бином?

Comment: сам файл лежит в корневике (в src/ - там же где и базовая дериктория объявления пакетов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то здесь не так...

Попробуйте, во-первых вывести значение свойства перед созданием ресурса. Так как свойство у вас типа String, то спринг изменять его не должен.

Во-вторых, удостоверьтесь, что в output-директории (`bin/`, `target/`...) действительно в папке с классами лежат оба файла (может, IDE шалит).

А еще - если вы хотите считать файл `.properties`, то, возможно, лучше будет воспользоваться `<util:properties />`. И в целом, для подключения ресурсов часто удобно пользоваться спринговским автомагическим распознаванием нужных значений по типу. Так, вы можете объявить свойство `File configFile` и указать в конфиге бина просто строку `<property name="configFile" value="classpath:file.txt" />` - и спринг создаст за вас файл из classpath'a.

Comment: Спасибо, @yozh, мне наоборот нельзя использовать `.properties`, т.к. сам файл - не проперти.
Попробую через Спринг сделать.